# Mocking AEM Asset Manager using WCM IO

Tags: junit, aem

I am creating a sling model which fetched a excel file from the file to read and display data in an AEM component.

```
@Model(
    adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class, 
    defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL
)
public class OnlineCoursesModel {

    @Self
    private SlingHttpServletRequest request;

    @ValueMapValue
    private String filePath;

    private List<OnlineCourseDTO> onlineCourses;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        AssetManager assetManager = request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(AssetManager.class);
        Asset asset = assetManager.getAsset(filePath);

        /** Do Something With the Asset **/
    }
}
```

In AEM it's working fine, but when I try to use it with the WCM.io AEM mocking framework, the `assetManager` is returning `null`.

```
@Test
public void checkIfFileIsRead() {
    context.load().binaryFile(COURSES_EXCEL_FILE, EXCEL_RESOURCE_PATH);
    context.load().json(ONLINE_COURSE_LISTING_AUTHORED, TEST_CONTENT_ROOT);
    resource = context.request();
    undertest = resource.adaptTo(OnlineCoursesModel.class);

    System.out.println(undertest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test is a little bit too complicated. Can you please try this simpler version:

```
@Test
public void checkIfFileIsRead() {
    context.create().asset("/content/dam/image.jpg", 1, 1, StandardImageHandler.JPEG_MIMETYPE);
    undertest = context.request().adaptTo(OnlineCoursesModel.class);

    assertNotNull(undertest);
}
```

This will create a new asset at `/content/dam/image.jpg` with a width of `1` and a height of `1` and mime type `image/jpg`.

You do not need to load a binary and additional json.

**Additional notes**

You also do not need to adapt from a request. That is considered bad practice and should only be done if you need specific information that is only part of the request. For example information about the user sending the request.

Otherwise, always adapt from `Resource.class`.

Example:

```
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class)
public class OnlineCoursesModel {

    @OSGiService
    private AssetManager assetManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Asset asset = assetManager.getAsset(filePath);

        /** Do Something With the Asset **/
    }
}
```